# Performance on query database with Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm looking in a method to get the best performance on getting data from database with a query, my main problem is that by doing the next example of query it give me an error `Message: preg_match(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large at offset 44123` that can be resolved by adding `PCRE library backtracking limit options` to `php,ini`.

It will resolve the issue on my server/hosting but not in others if will be used by many users.

My query is quite simple:

i have an array of 5k of rows:

```
$data = array(
  array('product_id' => 1),
  array('product_id' => 2),
  ++ 4998
);
```

i need to do a foreach to get the product id and ask the database for it and insert some data if exist if not it will return me back the product_id that doesn't exist, so i will store it in an array.

```
//Controller Method
    function test(){
        foreach($data as $row){
            $exist[] = $this->Model->AskDatabase($row->product_id);
        }

        if($exist){
            $getExistents = $exist;
        }

        if(!$getExistents == null){
             //And here is where the error is produced "regular expression is too large"
            $this->db->select('*')->from('products_2')->where_in('product_id', $getExistents)-get();
        }
    }

    //Model Method
    function AskDatabase($product_id){
        $exist = $this->db->select('id')->from('products')->where('product_id', $row->product_id)-get();

        if($exist->num_rows() > 0 ){
          return $exist->row()->id;
        }else{
          return false;
        }
    }
```

Is better to execute a foreach loop again with a 'where' condition instead where_in ? or is there another method that can get better performance on executing the query?

Any help is appreciated !